# explain these lines of mysql string Literals

Tags: mysql

I Have selected these lines from Mysql official site [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).
I am unable to understand what these lines means.

**There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:**

A “'” inside a string quoted with “'” may be written as “''”.

A “"” inside a string quoted with “"” may be written as “""”.

I did not understand how this sql.

mysql> SELECT  'hel''lo';

Outout: hel'lo

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You have a string inside single quotes, then it finds another quote, escaped by yet another code. So, it will translate into

```
'(start of string)hel'(escaping the next quote)'(the escaped quote)lo'(ending the string)
```

And thus outputting:

```
hel'lo
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. If you need to put a quote within a string literal delimited by those quotes, you can't use just a standalone quote character (like `'O'Brien'`) since there's no easy way to tell *which* of the second or third quote is the closing quote.

So they introduce a rule. If the SQL interpreter is within a quoted string and it finds another quote, it uses these rules:

- if the quote is immediately followed by another quote, assume the user wants one quote within the literal.
- otherwise it's the closing quote for the literal.

So, for example, consider:

```
select * from people where surname = 'O'Brien' order by id
```

Now you and I can tell which of those quotes actually terminates the string literal because we understand how names work. The computer does not take that for granted, instead requiring:

```
select * from people where surname = 'O''Brien' order by id
```

and turning the `''` inside the literal into a single `'`.